# How can I edit the URL of a .mp4 file to make it stream in browser?

Tags: url, browser, media-player, mp4, cdn

How can I edit the URL of a .mp4 file to make it stream in browser?
Lets say I have a .mp4 file hosted on a CDN.
What can I add to the URL for that file to play in browser?
I dont have any back end access to the CDN and am merely a user.

Example-

https://cdn-33.xxx.com/B1X5r2z332/dddsa/qweasdqwe.mp4

What would I add to this URL in order?

Would /player.php? work here?

Comment: The url of the mp4 should be enough. If struggling then provide a real **testable** url and we'll tell you how to make it work in a browser.

Comment: Hi, here is the link to the .mp4. The button has the CDN link.         https://anonfile.com/f54f4b04o3/IMG_0657_MP4

Answer (score 1):

> The button has the CDN link: `anonfile.com/f54f4b04o3/IMG_0657_MP4`

You can use the `<video>` tag in your HTML page to play the CDN link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="https://cdn-02.anonfile.com/f54f4b04o3/0364d3da-1589754461/IMG_0657.MP4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

**PS:**
You will notice your page link has this icon:
 https://anonfile.com/img/file/filetypes/mime/video_unknown.png?1554382134

With a name like `video_unknown.png` that could be a clue that something is wrong, or at least is causing the file not to work inside a browser tab.

Checking your mp4's file bytes I see that a section called `MDAT` (which is media data) has a hard-coded size number of **1** but is then followed by **649213** bytes of actual media data.

Normally an mp4 has `MOOV` (metadata/settings for playback) then followed by `MDAT` (the actual playback data). Your file is arranged opposite with `MDAT` first, not a bad thing since an MPEG decoder is supposed to check this size and just skip to the metadata. Well your file says "media data size is 1 byte in length" so now the browser's decoder skips 1 byte and when it finds no metadata bytes saying `MOOV` it gives up and downloads the file to disk (hoping you know a software to handle such a corrupt file). The `MOOV` section itself had correct size shown as **6059** for the metadata.

Media players (or `<video>` tag) can play it once file is fully downloaded since the whole file is available to scan for metadata (which itself has the byte positions for each video frames)

Comment: Is it possible to instruct that to the browser through the URL? In other words, what can I add or remove to the static CDN url that will instruct it to play the video?               Something like this - https://example.com/player.php?stream=CNBC except instead of a stream, I just want to play video without uploading all the html to a site and executing it. Not too sure if some backend knowledge  from the site might be needed